# Why is it necessary to annotate mapped Date fields @Temporal in javax.persistence?

Tags: java, orm, persistence

The format goes like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
private Date createdDate;
```

My question is:  Why is it necessary to annotate mapped `java.util.Date` fields as `@Temporal` in [`javax.persistence`](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa)?  If the local variable is obviously declared as a Date and the column data type in the DB is also one of the date(time) or timestamp types, shouldn't it be easy to infer that we're dealing with a temporal bit of data without redundantly specifying it in multiple places?

Answer (score 8):

From e.g. java.util.Date it's not obvious if one wants to map to DATE or TIMESTAMP database type. Only exception is java.sql.Date/Time.

Comment: thanks but i fail to see how this answers my question

Comment: well what if you want to create your db table from your jpa annotated code?

Comment: how does it matter?  and why would anyone want to create a DB table from JPA annotations?

Comment: and how is it different from other data types?

Comment: 1) for simple projects it's quite common to let the orm create your tables  2) it differs for all other datatypes there is a 1:1 relation (e.g. string- varchar and so on). a related problem is e.g. boolean conversion (T/F vs Y/N) and the possibility to provide custom converters see: AttributeConverter

Comment: it's explained in more detail here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Temporal.2C_Dates.2C_Times.2C_Timestamps_and_Calendars

Answer (score 5):

When you want to store a `java.util.Date` in database, it can be done in three different ways:

1- store just the date (`java.sql.Date`): year/month/day

2- store date and time (`java.sql.Time`): Date + hour/minute/second

3- store timestamp (`java.sql.Timestamp`): Date + Time + nano seconds

With providing `@Temporal` You have to select `TemporalType.DATE`, `TemporalType.TIME`, or `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` to determine the accuracy of your `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 1):

From the wikipedia page, this answered it for me:

"If you map a Java java.sql.Date type to a database DATE, this is just a basic mapping and you should not have any issues (ignore Oracle's DATE type that is/was a timestamp for now). You can also map java.sql.Time to TIME, and java.sql.Timestamp to TIMESTAMP. However if you have a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar in Java and wish to map it to a DATE or TIME, you may need to indicate that the JPA provider perform some sort of conversion for this. In JPA the @Temporal annotation or  element is used to map this. You can indicate that just the DATE or TIME portion of the date/time value be stored to the database. You could also use Temporal to map a java.sql.Date to a TIMESTAMP field, or any other such conversion."

So in short, you need @Temporal as a conversion layer between your java type and the target database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your database tables from your jpa annotated code (On server startup, etc) then the @Temporal annotation is necessary