# not able to retrieve object from datebase by passing date

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve object from database by passing date but it is returning null even though the object in database with that date.can any one help me please

my code:

```
@RequestMapping("/getavailableslots")
public Object getAvialableSlot(){   
    Date date=new Date();
    List<Dates> dates=repository.findByDate(date);
    return dates;
}
```

jpa repository:

```
public interface DateReposotory extends JpaRepository<Dates, Integer> {
    Dates findByDate(Date date);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Dates {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @Column(name="date")
    Date date;

    @Column(name="slots")
    String[] slots;

    @Column(name="month")
    int month;
    //setters and getters goes here
}
```

I am saving dates in database as

```
@RequestMapping("/adddates")
public void addDates(){

    String[] slts={"11am","12am","13am","14am"};
    Date date=new Date();
    Dates dates=new Dates();    
    dates.setDate(date);
    dates.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    dates.setSlots(slts);
    dr.save(dates);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate `Date date` attribute of your entity class with `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` in order to achieve proper conversion between DATE in db and java.util.Date. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27430318/3535298).

Answer (score 0):

declare in Entity as:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
```

passing in jpa query:

```
repository.findByDate(new Date("2017/03/14"));
```